# What does This branch has not been deployed mean in Github?

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment

What does this mean in Github? Why does this specific PR not run any automatic checks while other PRs in the repo have automatic checks run?

[image: Screenshot of This branch has not been deployed in Github]

Comment: Check @clausjoergensen discussion at https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/45186 or the accepted solution at https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/46375. Anyway for me this message disappeared from the PR once it was merged.

Answer (score -6):

I had the same issue and was due to an error (in the indentation) in the yml workflow file (`.github/workflow/my-workflow.yml`).